# Where to find documentation of building ubuntu kernel

Tags: kernel, compiling

I want to build ubuntu's kernel with my code for raspberry 3b.

where can I find documentation to follow build kernel?

I found these two git

- 20.04 : git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/focal
- 18.04 : git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source/linux/+git/bionic

Comment: @sarru1291 thanks to the reply. but any ubuntu's kernel wiki about raspberry pi (3b, 4b)?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi I don't think there is a special article for raspi ubuntu kernel. you can look at the previous link and figure out for raspberry pi replacing focal fossa.